# Date Picker Now. Cocoa-OSX Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa

How can I make the date picker show the date and time that is now? Without clicking nothing, just at the beginning. I am very new in Cocoa, I would appreciate any orientation.

This is what I have done:
- I create a new project > OSX > Application > Cocoa Application
- Main.storyboard. Drag a Date Picker
- Ctrl + drag from date picker to ViewController.swift. I give it the name datePicker: @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: NSDatePicker!

Comment: Add `[datePicker setDateValue:[NSDate new]];` in viewdidLoad of View Controller

Comment: @Kaunteya this gives me an error. Are you sure this is Swift?

Comment: Oh sorry. You can `datePicker.dateValue = NSDate()` would solve your problem. Please get your basics right. It is not very hard to map obj-c to swift

Comment: It works, thank you. You should put that in the answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[datePicker setDateValue:[NSDate new]];` in viewdidLoad of View Controller

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that returns the hour and the day and corrects for different time zones, I am using 7 for Nevada PST time zone but you can update for your specific state

```
 func returnHourDay() -> (Int, Int) {
    let dateNow = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var Hour = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.hour, from: dateNow)
    let Day = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.weekday, from: dateNow)

    //correct for specific time zones
    func ltzOffset() -> Int { return NSTimeZone.local.secondsFromGMT() }
    let hourOffset = 7 + ltzOffset()/60/60  //0 for Nevada 7 - 7 = 0
    Hour = Hour+hourOffset

    return (Hour, Day)
}
```